# Is there a way to internationalize/localize model values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

Our users put documents into the database and provide e.g. names in different languages.

We store those in different DB fields, say `name_en`, `name_fr`, `name_de` and so on.

My question is:

Does Rails have a mechanism (probably provided by i18n) that selects the right name based on the current language setting?

I imagine a call like:

`<%= t(document, :name) %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gem may help https://github.com/globalize/globalize

I hope you will find this information useful.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. I was aware of globalize already and knew what it is doing, but your mention prompted me to look at it again, and while it is not what I'm looking for, I found [https://github.com/barsoom/traco] in the ReadMe, which I will be using now. So you basically solved my problem. Points to you!

Answer (score 2):

While Anton pointed me in its direction I want it to have a separate answer, so this is what I think is the best solution to my particular problem:

[**Traco**](https://github.com/barsoom/traco) lets me stick with my current scheme of having **translations of an attribute distributed of different columns in the same table**.

Comment: I have the same problem you just confirm that is the solution.